# How to change the color of the dropdown that appears with ctrl + shift + p in VSCode

Tags: themes, visual-studio-code

I was trying to edit some themes on my Vscode but got stuck at this point since I don't know what this section is referred as, that we pop up by `ctrl + shift + p`

[image: Section that appears with ctrl + shift + p]

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.background": "#101a29",
    "sideBar.foreground": "#CAC9C9",
    "sideBarSectionHeader.foreground": "#CAC9C9",
    "editorGroupHeader.tabsBorder": "#c93e71",
    "editor.selectionBackground": "#ff6d6d32",
    "editor.wordHighlightBackground": "#ff6d6d32"
  },
```

I've did these many changes so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primarily that is the `quickInput` so

```
"quickInput.background": "#f00"
```

will work.  If you don't style the `quickInput` then the more generic `editorWidget` will also work but will also style other things, like the Find Widget.

```
"editorWidget.foreground": "#000",
"editorWidget.background": "#a8c0a8",
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually its two groups commandCenter which is the input box and editorWidget which is the drop down for example from my own theme

```
 "commandCenter.border": "#e7e7e799",
"commandCenter.activeBackground": "#ff0095",
"commandCenter.inactiveForeground": "#f3f0f0",
"commandCenter.inactiveBorder": "#6f00ff",
"commandCenter.activeForeground": "#130101",
"editorWidget.background": "#cb43f5",
"editorWidget.foreground": "#fcf7fb",
"editorWidget.border": "#ff00bf",
```